# WSGI.py django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application

Tags: python, django, wsgi

Обновлял WhiteNoise и вносил изменения в wsgi.py Затем узнал, что в новой версии уже не нужно редактировать WSGI. Вернул обратно, но теперь выдает ошибку
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'mysite.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.

Не могу найти ошибку. Вот код. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

```
settings.py
    import os
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', True))
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'polls',
'hello',
'ris',
'tot',
'quest',
'accounts',
'child',
'own', 'quantity_3',
'child_6',
'child_9',
'a_6',
'a_9',]


   MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',]


  ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

  TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
           
        ],
    },
},]

  WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

  DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}}

     AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',)


     AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},]

   LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

   TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

   USE_I18N = True

   USE_L10N = True

   USE_TZ = True


   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'polls/static'),
# Add to this list all the locations containing your static files)


   # Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
   import dj_database_url
   db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
   DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)'
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


  os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
  application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Структура проекта:
djangogirls

- my-first-blog

  - mysite

    - wsgi.py